# C# file corruption

Tags: c#, file, corruption

I saved a working C# project last night but when I reopened it today, there are numerous (>2000) errors.  It seems like XML code was injected into certain portions and parts of modules were cut and pasted onto the other modules, without any rhyme or reason.  In short, everything is mixed up.

Any idea what could have caused this? and if there are any solutions?

Comment: Are you using version control? Something like this can happen when there are conflicts

Comment: Yes, it conforms to our configuration control procedures; I've just never seen anything like this before

Comment: It sounds like a bad merge. Can you just reset to the most recent version?

Comment: I was able to use the most recent version, but still not quite sure what caused the corruption in the first place

Comment: Like I said, it sounds like a bad merge but without seeing what the actual manifestation of this "corruption" is there's no way to beyond a guess.